# How to commit project in existing bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I have created a .NET project which I want to commit into my existing bitbucket repository.I am trying this through `Git Bash`.

These are the steps which I followed but unable to commit the project. Can anyone please guide me.

[image]

Anyone please guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got suggests that you haven't linked a remote repository to your local one, hence  Git Bash doesn't know where to push  the changes. Try this:

```
git remote add origin <link of your remote repo>
```

You can find the link like this:

[image]

Comment: I did your solution. Can you please show me the path from here. I have spent couple of hours trying different solutions but nothing was working for me. Aprreciated if you could provide me the complete solution.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to guide you. Have you successfully added the remote repo (the command I posted above) ?

Comment: It is showing something like this `Rajesh@RAJESH-LAPTOP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/ParseTheParcel (master)
$ git remote add origin git clone https://rajeshyadav1982@bitbucket.org/trademe/parsetheparcel-rajesh-yadav.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
    -f, --fetch  fetch the remote branches
    --tags  import all tags and associated objects when fetching
    or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
      master branch
    --mirror[=(push|fetch)]
     set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from`

Comment: `git remote add origin https://rajeshyadav1982@bitbucket.org/trademe/parsetheparcel-rajesh-yadav.git `

Comment: This will work if you have generated a SSH key on your PC otherwise it won't, I still recommend you change the link to the HTTPS one and copy that one from Bitbucket (See the picture above). Instead of SSH select HTTPS and copy that link

Comment: Now it is showing `$ git remote add origin https://rajeshyadav1982@bitbucket.org/trademe/parsetheparcel-rajesh-yadav.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180655/discussion-between--and-frame).

Answer (score 1):

Follow These Steps:

```
1: git add .
2: git commit -m "your commit message here"
3: git push origin master
```

Comment: When I try your solution, it gives following error `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: there is no problem with these steps first. you have to add remote repository to push changes. use this command 
 -   git remote add origin <link of your remote repo>
Link is same as you clone your repo. just remove git clone before that.
-    git remote add origin https://raj.............